# exert power VS wield power

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-choice, word-meaning

Does **exert power over something** mean the same as **wield power over something**?
For example:

1. For many centuries, this community *exerted* a lot of *power over* these
   people.
2. For many centuries, this community *wielded* a lot of *power over* these
   people.

Would sentence 1 and 2 mean exactly the same?

Comment: I would say that when you **wield** power it is a stance, not an action. When you **exert** that power, there is an effect. For **wield** please see [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/wield): *Have and be able to use (power or influence).*

Comment: @WeatherVane, The definition you mentioned is the second one, but the first one says "hold and use", so It does not seem to me that it does not mean an action.

Comment: The first definition is for an *object* such as a weapon. The second seems to be for your requested meaning. But anyway, someone wields a sword: they brandish it. In the example, the robber wielding a handgun, it does not mean 'shooting'.

Comment: @WeatherVane, I see your point, but could they be, in some cases, interchangeable? If I say "This wields influence over that", how can something wield influence over something else without actually influencing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wield power without exerting it.

For instance, a policeman standing on a street corner can reduce crime (or at least relocate it) without actually arresting any criminals. The fact he *could* arrest people has an effect on their behavior.